# Repacking of the squashfs file

Tags: 12.04, squashfs

How to unpack and repack squashed `system.img` file? My Ubuntu version is 12.04

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to install the squashfs tools:

```
sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools
```

There are some useful notes on how to use the squashfs tools here:  http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SquashFS-HOWTO/mksqoverview.html
and
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SquashFS-HOWTO/creatingandusing.html